# the name does not exist in current context (windows form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# and I know the answer is very simple I just could not find it through searching

I created two buttons the first one generates random values
and the second one is an IF statement inside another button, but I`m getting a red line under 1value1 saying

> the name does not exists in current context

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random b = new Random();
    float value = b.Next(50, 100);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (value < MinValue)
    {
       textBox18.Text = ("warning");
       textBox18.ForeColor = Color.White;
       textBox18.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `float value` has to be declared outside your button event handlers

Comment: please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx) to understand scopes.

Comment: define globally  `value ` and  `MinValue`

Answer (score 1):

`value` is defined in the scope of the `button3_Click` and thus not accessible for the `button2_Click`. Put it as a variable of the class:

```
private int _minValue = 50;
private int _maxValue = 100;

private float _value = _maxValue;

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random b = new Random();
    _value = b.Next(_minValue, _maxValue);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_value < _minValue)
    {
        textBox18.Text = ("warning");
        textBox18.ForeColor = Color.White;
        textBox18.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lupin - If this solved the question please mark as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Set property `GenerateMember=True`

Comment: Can you expand this answer?